# Can I use Workflow Foundation to enable transactions with Azure Storage?

Tags: c#, azure, transactions, workflow-foundation-4, azure-storage

I'm considering using Workflow Foundation 4 to handle not only my error handling with Azure Storage, but [also to leverage the engine for transactions.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff470395%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

- Is this a good idea?
- What special considerations should I do when porting a high-load storage engine to Workflow?
- What providers must I replace and port to Azure storage?  (eg persistence provider, or some provider related to transactions?)

Comment: I answered a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18045517/do-azure-storage-related-apis-participate-in-system-transactions/18046133#18046133) yesterday about Storage and transactions. See if that helps.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I subscribe (email alerts) for Azure Storage and that question (your answer) made me ask this one.  I understand that the Azure primitives need to be invoked to emulate a transaction  (Locking a blob as explained in the storage whitepaper, etc).  Since WF4 handles APM style async failures (`try..catch`) perhaps this can be used to "rough out" some tx handling, either at the UI layer in try/catch or at a lower layer (replace some WF4 xProvider).

Comment: (edit: I can't find it in the whitepaper, but I do remember seeing a technique promoted by Microsoft saying that it's possible to use a lease on a blob to act as a transaction)  My intent it to wrap blob leasing into WF4 to get clean APM code with lock (pseudo-transaction) functionality.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with that? I implemented a pseudo-transaction for this but it doesn't lock the files, just takes care of rollbacks if the transaction fails.