# distribuited coordinator on windows azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage, distributed-transactions

I'm using the DTC on windows azure SQL. 
The Transaction coordinator works fine and I want to know if there's a way to use it with tablestorage or blob storage.
The functionality can will very utils to have a unique transaction in more service.

Answer (score 0):

I've searched but there's no information about DTC on the official doc. But it seems that it's not possible yet: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18046133/1384539